# fastcgi.conf; vs fastcgi-php.conf snippet?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

Actually whats the difference between the two? My web sites work fine with :

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
  }
```

However i see that some guides on internet also add the snippet to the above code, like:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}
```

But i see that the snippet also includes fastcgi.conf inside. So why shall we add include fastcgi.conf?

And what does the snippet do more than fastcgi.conf?